# how to use Data Driven Adapters for CCA and Integrating in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, aif

I am Working on CRM CCA. I want to Create Data Driven Adapters to communicate with other Applications. but i am not able to Create Data Driven Adapter. Can any body Help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sure that somebody might be able to help you here, but without seeing what you have tried so far this might be difficult. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27794911/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly Yo are not working on CRM-CCA ,cause if were you would know these things .
any way i will tell you . 
visit this link [to see code](https://github.com/TheThirdRichNiggers/CCA_APP_for_DDA.git)  and check out [this blog](https://aviktheprogrammer.wordpress.com/)